# How to add a conditional routing between href and routerlink in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a variable that have either

1. `/my/internal/route`
   or
2. `https://externalroute.ch`.

On the first option, I'll just route to the target pages, which is lazy loaded.
On the second, I'll open it into a new page.

I've tried to to do it like this

```html
<a [routerLink]="url" [target]="url.includes('https') ? '_blank' : '_self'">my link</a>
```

and to follow this [idea](https://coryrylan.com/blog/managing-external-links-safely-in-angular)

But none of them worked.

#### Requirement

I need to make my website crawlable by the google SEO bots. It's the reason why I haven't done it with a method.

Comment: I didn't got your point you need to make it crawlable by SEO. I guess crawlers will easily crawl these right? What's your doubt over here?

Comment: It was, if I did it like that `<a openLink(url)>my link</a>` I will surely find a way to make it work, but then it wont be crawlable. (I think, not sure though). but the way I did it isn't working, it wont open it in a new tab.

Comment: I feel the above method you mentioned in question is SEO friendly. However you may not wanted to put a direct function call in the `[target]` hence would recommend it to pipe it out.

Comment: yes, but when I click on the link, then it will add the domain of the website -> `https:/...` become `locahost:4200/https://...` Do you now how to avoid ? It's maybe because the page is loaded through an Iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the example added in the example do works, but it wasn't for me. *maybe because I'm running the website through an Iframe*.

But I did come with a solution that add the correct attributes, depending if I have another host name or not. It is the best solution I could come up with.

1. Creating a directive
2. Listening on change
3. Analyzing if the url does contain the same namespace as the actual website.
4. If not, add the required attributes & subscribe to the on click listener *because for me the default one wasn't working*

```js
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common'
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, Inject, Input, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: 'a[href]',
})
export class ExternalLinkDirective {
  @HostBinding('attr.rel') relAttr = null
  @HostBinding('attr.target') targetAttr = null
  @HostBinding('attr.href') hrefAttr = ''
  @Input() href: string

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.hrefAttr = this.href

    if (this.isLinkExternal()) {
      this.relAttr = 'noopener'
      this.targetAttr = '_blank'

      this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'noopener')
      })
    }
  }

  private isLinkExternal() {
    return (
      this.href?.includes('http')
    )
  }
}
```

*Thx to [this article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/managing-external-links-safely-in-angular) which give me the code*